# How to display cache images into html div object

Tags: javascript, image-caching

I'm searching for the way to display any image preloaded in a **Javascript** ***Image*** array in a chosen **html** object, because I couldn't find the way to do it so far: So, could you please help me write my function "***affiche***()", considering what follows:

for example, let's suppose we want to set a picture into a  object called ***stand***

now, the images have been loaded in cache as follows:

```
<script type= text/javascript>
    // ...
    var tbPix = new Array;
    tbPix[1]= new Image();
    tbPix[2]= new Image();
    tbPix[3]= new Image();
    tbPix[1].src = 'image1.jpg";
    tbPix[2].src = 'image2.jpg";
    tbPix[3].src = 'image3.jpg";
    // ...
</script>
```

finally, we want to write the "affiche" function, with the following signature, so as to be able to call it like in the following example where we want to display the picture **'image2'** from the Javascript cache into the **'stand'** div:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // ...
    affiche('stand',tbPix[2])
    // ...
    function affiche(divName,javaPic)
    {
        // give me the code, please!
    }
    // ...
</script>
```

Thank you very much by the way, dear 11501525 (well, I don't know your name) because tour answer was both fast and precisely what I needed. here's my function, knowing the same div object must contain no more than one image, so a new image has to replace the previous one, and not to be added:

```
function affiche(nomDiv, javaPic) //->void
{   // Place l'image javaPic dans l'objet nomDiv en remplacement de tout autre 
    var x = document.getElementById(nomDiv);
    x.innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(nomDiv).appendChild(javaPic);
}
```

Thanks a lot, once more.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are searching for is appendChild:

```
divName.appendChild(javaPic);
```

Edit:

Sorry, i didn't saw that your first parameter was a string.

You need a html object in ordner to use appendChild.

If your object has the id stand, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('stand').appendChild(javaPic);
```